# How to build ionic project with gradle version 8.6

Tags: gradle, ionic-framework

everyone.

I hope you are doing well.

I upgraded gradle version from v8.2.2 to v8.6.

And I am trying to build to release apk with Android Studio released on 24 Feb 2023.

But it doesn't support gradle latest version, till v8.2.2, so I need to build with this command, gradlew assembleDebug.

It occurs this error.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I would like to build ionic app with Gradle v8.6.

Anyone has experienced with this, please give me advises.

Thank you.

I tried to build apk with Android Studio, Gradle v8.6.

Also tried with this command, gradlew assembleDebug.

It happens error, so I would like to build release apk successfully.